# Image is not showing on the .jar file Eclipse

Tags: java, image, jar

Hi when i export my project to a .jar file the images don´t appear but whe i run the code in eclipse i can see them. I tryed many solutions i saw on google but anyone works fine for me. The images are in the Imagenes folder, in the same level of src.
This is my code:

```
   package Booo;


import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Ventana {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MarcoPrincipal mimarco=new MarcoPrincipal();
        mimarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mimarco.setVisible(true);
        
    }

}

class MarcoPrincipal extends JFrame {
    
    public MarcoPrincipal() {
        
        setTitle("Invitación PJM Lujan 2021");
        Toolkit mipantalla=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        setBounds(400, 10, 750, 850);
        this.setResizable(false);
        Image miIcono=mipantalla.getImage("Imagenes/pjm.jpeg"); //icono del PJM
        setIconImage(miIcono);
        fondoPanel  fondo= new fondoPanel();
        this.setContentPane(fondo);
        LaminaPrincipal lamina =new LaminaPrincipal();
        lamina.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,200,300));
        add(lamina);
        
    }
    
    
}

class LaminaPrincipal extends JPanel{
    
    public LaminaPrincipal() {
        
        
        this.setOpaque(false);
        JButton botonOpen=new JButton("Abrir la Invitación");
        add(botonOpen);
        
        OyenteNuevo oyente=new OyenteNuevo();
        botonOpen.addActionListener(oyente);
        
        
    }
    private class OyenteNuevo implements ActionListener{
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        MarcoEmergente marco=new MarcoEmergente();
        marco.setVisible(true);
        
        }
        
    }
    
}

class MarcoEmergente extends JFrame{
    
    public MarcoEmergente () {
                
        Toolkit mipantalla=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image miIcono=mipantalla.getImage("Imagenes/pjm.jpeg"); //icono del PJM
        setIconImage(miIcono);  
        setTitle("Invitación PJM Luján 2021");      
        Dimension tamanoPantalla= mipantalla.getScreenSize();
        int alturaPantalla=tamanoPantalla.height;
        int anchoPantalla=tamanoPantalla.width;
        setSize(500,750);
        setLocation(500,50);
        textoImg lamina1=new textoImg(); //agrego la lamina
        add(lamina1);
        this.setResizable(false);
                
    }
    
}

class textoImg extends JPanel{
    
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        File miimagen = new File("Imagenes/inv.jpg");
        try {
        imagen2 = ImageIO.read(miimagen);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("xd");
        }
        this.setOpaque(false);
        g.drawImage(imagen2, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),this );
        
        setOpaque(false);
    
        //g2.drawString("¿Cuándo? El jueves 8 de julio", 150, 100);
        
    }
    private Image imagen2;
    
}



class fondoPanel extends JPanel{
    
    private Image imagen;
    
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        File miimagen2 = new File("Imagenes/back.jpg");
        try {
            imagen = ImageIO.read(miimagen2);
            
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Sds");
        }
        this.setOpaque(false);
        g.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),this);
        
        setOpaque(false);
        
        
    }
    
}
```

and this is my folder the one called pipi:
[image]

Comment: `Imagenes` folder is not in the classpath outside eclipse.

Comment: Where should it go??

Comment: Usually under `src/main/resources`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar